# How to make @storybook/addon-storysource work for vue

Tags: vue.js, storybook

my directory structure:

├── .storybook

│  ├── webpack.config.js

│  ├── addons.js

│  ├── config.js

├── stories
│  ├── index.story.js

my addons.js

```
import '@storybook/addon-actions/register'
import '@storybook/addon-storysource/register'
```

my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = function({ config }) {
    config.module.rules.push(
        {
            test: /\.story\.js?$/,
            loaders: [require.resolve('@storybook/addon-storysource/loader')],
            enforce: 'pre'
        },
        ...styleLoader
    )

    return config
}
```

storysource doesn't work

Story show loading source...